# laravel 5.1: redirecting in AuthController doesn't work (using xampp)

Tags: xampp, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel 5.1 and I am trying to make it possible for users to log in to my app. I'm doing this in xampp, so my login path looks like this: http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/auth/login.

However, when I try to log in it redirects me to http://localhost/auth/login and gives a 404 error. It does this too when the login fails. I have tried to set the 'protected $redirectPath' and 'protected $loginPath' in the AuthController to something like localhost/laravel/public/index.php/ to get to the home page, but it doesn't work and still goes to http://localhost/auth/login. I would be very grateful to anyone that could help me out or explain to me how I can make the redirecting work after logging in or failing to log in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its better to use

```
php artisan serve
```

in your project route if you're developing in localhost because you can control your routes more easily and you can get rid of  localhost/laravel/public/index.php/ .

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed my own problem: it turns out that I was posting my login form to /auth/login (I had just copied the example from the laravel docs), so I changed that to /laravel/public/index.php/auth/login and now everything is acting as it should again!